# How to Install HTK on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, htk

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326026/android-offline-voice-recognition) question. Since I don't want to pass the voice data to a server, doing this may cost me more time. I wonder if I can use [HTK](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/) to recognize the voice data locally with the Android application so that I won't need to pass that audio to the server.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013785/how-to-build-third-party-libraries-with-android-ndk) may be the solution, but can anyone give me a more detialed tutorial on how to build HTK with android ndk? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `pocketsphinx` is more suitable for you, see this tutorial: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid . And to build the JNI API from `pocketsphinx` yourself, see [Building PocketSphinxAndroidDemo (from CMUSphinx project)](http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=118) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, we can compile HTK using NDK.:)

Comment: Yeah, pocketsphinx is also not written in Java and should compile using NDK. I recommended pocketsphinx because it's more exquisite compared with HTK, and the accuracy is not bad. What's more pocketsphinx is more suitable for mobile devices.

Comment: this does not answer the original question